Is the intercept of a complex sum-coded regression basically useless for interpretation? Maybe even for some simple models?
In regression analysis, one may choose to code categorical variables differently depending on interpretability considerations. One such coding scheme known as sum coding (a kind of effect coding similar to deviation coding) is implemented in R as "sum contrasts".
Usually, effect coding is advertised as a way to compare the means of categorical variables to the grand mean of the response variable defined as the mean of the means of the levels of the categorical variable(s?) in question. However, I have found that this only seems to apply in very specific situations. I will present some scenarios related to the interpretation of the intercept regression coefficient with sum coding. Preparing some data to demonstrate them in R...
xdf <- mtcars
xdf$cyl <- factor(xdf$cyl)
xdf$vs <- factor(xdf$vs)
xdf$am <- factor(xdf$am)

Situation 1
# simple model with 1 categorical variable
naive <- lm(
    mpg ~ cyl,
    xdf,
    contrasts = list(cyl = contr.sum)
)
coef(naive)[1] # 20.50216
mean(tapply(xdf$mpg, xdf$cyl, mean)) # 20.50216

This is the classical example for sum coding: only 1 categorical variable. One can verify that the intercept is indeed the unweighted grand mean of the response variable across levels of cyl.
Situation 2
# simple interaction model with 2 categorical variables
simpleInt <- lm(
    mpg ~ vs * am,
    xdf,
    contrasts = list(vs = contr.sum, am = contr.sum)
)
coef(simpleInt)[1] # 20.9785714
mean(tapply(xdf$mpg, list(xdf$vs, xdf$am), mean)) # 20.97857

This one is also fairly well advertised. Here the means that are to be averaged are the means of the combinations of factors of both categorical variables.
Situation 3
# numerical-categorial interaction model with 2 variables
numCatInt <- lm(
    mpg ~ vs * hp,
    xdf,
    contrasts = list(vs = contr.sum)
)
coef(numCatInt)[1] # 31.74846
mean(tapply(xdf$mpg, xdf$vs, mean)) # 20.5869

Here is when it starts to get a bit weird. According to the UCLA examples on the topic (this link also includes well-explained examples for the previous 2 situations), here the intercept should be also the mean of the means of vs as at the intercept, hp is assumed to be 0 anyway. I was unable to recreate this though
Situation 4
# 2 categorical variables without interaction 
twoCat <- lm(
    mpg ~ vs + am,
    xdf,
    contrasts = list(vs = contr.sum, am = contr.sum)
)
coef(twoCat)[1] # 21.09246
mean(tapply(xdf$mpg, list(xdf$vs, xdf$am), mean)) # 20.97857

What is even going on here? I feel like this one should be really easy to understand but I was unable to come to terms with the meaning of the intercept here. I also was unable to find anything anywhere except this other post where the only answer does what I'm doing here and also doesn't get the same number. It is implied in the post that it is because there is no data for 1 of the combinations between the levels of the variables but here I made sure to use 2 variables where there is data for the 4 possible combinations of levels.
Beyond these specific situations, it seems to me that the interpretation of the intercept with sum contrasts can very quickly diverge from simply the grand mean. We could have a moderately complex model, say mpg ~ (hp + am + cyl) * vs, and it seems that it already would be pretty hard to put a meaning on the intercept. For interpreting continuous variable coefficients, this might no be that big of a deal. For instance, for the aforementioned model I can just say something like: "the coefficient of hp is the average change in mpg across the levels of am for a unit change in hp after adjusting for other variables". However, for categorical variables, it seems that with sum coding the interpretation of coefficients is always relative to the intercept. For example, it would be neat to be able to say "the coefficient of am is the average deviation in mpg from the grand mean across the levels of vs when am = 1 after adjusting for other variables" (assuming the dropped out level of am is 0). This last statement is not true because the intercept is not the grand mean in this model as defined previously nor it is clear if this intercept represents some meaningful quantity anymore.
Does the intercept term just become useless for interpretation at this point?
I was thinking that as an alternative to put the coefficients of the categorical variables "into context", one could instead forget about the intercept, and just look at the difference between the coefficients for the levels of interest. For example: "the average change in mpg across levels of vs when switching from am = 0 to am = 1 is [insert here difference of the 2 coefficients corresponding to the main effects of the levels of am] after adjusting for other variables". The coefficient that is not in the model can be calculated or just extracted from a second fit changing the dropped out level, or if its a binary predictor it's just the same coefficient as the one shown but with a flipped sign. What do you think about this alternative?
